# Update BST nodes in range

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I have an AVL Tree which also calculate the index of each node (rank tree), I need to implement a function that gets minimum and maximum values and do the following:

1. Check how much elements of the tree falls inside this range (by the key of the nodes).
2. If the number of elements is a power of 2 it should update the elements key as so: (i =number of elements)

add 1 to the largest i/2 elements

add 1 to the largest i/4 elements

add 1 to the largest i/8 elements

...

add 1 to the largest element

3. Returns the largest element in the range.

The complexity of this function should be O(log(i)*log(nodes_amount))

I was able to solve 1 and 3 base on the rank tree, I calculate how many nodes are less than maximum value and subtract the number of elements less than the minimum value, this cost O(log (nodes_amount)).

Returning the largest element in the range also possible in O(log (nodes_amount)) based on the AVL tree search.

The problem is with section 2 of the function which I can't figure out how to i-1 updates can be done in the required complexity.

It is possible that my approach isn't correct and BST isn't the solution for this problem.